# How to return/realign/reunite a branch of a tree structure to the original parent lineage using the forest package?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-styles, forest, trees, branching

I am drawing etymological trees using `forest` and I am wondering if I can reunite my forked-off branches back with the main "line" somehow.

Essentially the question could also be: Can one child node have two parent nodes? If not, then I am happy to `\draw`, but it would be nice to align it symmetrically (see attached image). I am using `LuaLaTeX`.

Here is my code so far:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[edges, linguistics]{forest}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={align=center,calign=center}
        [paprika\\{English},tier=a,baseline
        [paprika\\{Hungarian},tier=b
        [paprika\\{Serbian-Croatian-Bosnian},tier=c
        [*pĭpĭrĭ\\{Proto-Slavic},tier=d
        [piper\\{Latin},tier=e
        [péperi\\{Ancient Greek},name=AG,tier=f 
        [?\\{Pahlavi},tier=g
        [pipparī\\{Middle Indo-Aryan},tier=h
        [pippalī\\{Sanskrit},tier=i]]]]]] 
        [piperi\\{Modern Greek},name=MG]]]]
        \draw[-] (AG.north) to (MG.south);
    \end{forest}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image: Current tree (left) and desired tree shape (right)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the node can only have a single formal parent. So `\draw` it is, in principle. However, as I often need to fake an extra parent (or child) myself, I wrote the `edge to/from` styles you can see in the code.

Regarding the main, realignment question, one way to do this is to override the value of `s` computed by Forest's packing algorithm. (`s` is the position of the node relative to its parent, in the dimension perpendicular to the tree growth; see section 3.7.2 of the manual.) In the example, Latin is a single (formal) child, so Forest sets its `s=0`. But Latin's parent, Proto-Slavic, has its own (negative) `s`, relative to SCB. So if we set the `s` of Latin to the negative of PS `s`, we will effectively align it with SCB. This is achieved by `s=-s("!u")`.

We have to perform this assignment at just the right time: after Forest has computed the `s` values (i.e. after "packing"), but before it translates the ls-coordinates into xy-coordinates (see manual section 3.4.1 on stages). So we arrive at `before computing xy={s=-s("!u")`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[edges, linguistics]{forest}

% Easy extra edges
\forestset{
  % From an "extra parent" to the node:
  edge to'/.style 2 args={% #1 = the extra parent, #2 = the edge style
    tikz+={\path[#2](#1.parent anchor)--(.child anchor);}
  },
  % From an "extra parent" to the node 
  % using the current edge style:
  % (If the )
  edge to/.style={% #1 = the extra parent
    edge to'/.expanded={\unexpanded{#1}}{\forestoption{edge}},
  },
  % From the node to an "extra child":
  edge from'/.style 2 args={% #1 = the extra child, #2 = the edge style
    tikz+={\path[#2](.parent anchor)--(#1.child anchor);}
  },
  % From the node to an "extra child" 
  % using the current edge style (of the extra child):
  edge from/.style={% #1 = the extra child
    edge from'/.process=_O{#1}{#1.edge},
  },
}
% The "extra parent/child" may be given as a relative node name. 
% So in the example below, we could replace
% "edge to=MG" with "edge to=!uus" (uus=up,up,sibling).

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={align=center,calign=center}
    [paprika\\{English},tier=a,baseline
    [paprika\\{Hungarian},tier=b
    [paprika\\{Serbian-Croatian-Bosnian},tier=c
    [*pĭpĭrĭ\\{Proto-Slavic},tier=d
    [piper\\{Latin},tier=e, before computing xy={s=-s("!u")},
    [péperi\\{Ancient Greek},name=AG,tier=f, edge to=MG,
    [?\\{Pahlavi},tier=g
    [pipparī\\{Middle Indo-Aryan},tier=h
    [pippalī\\{Sanskrit},tier=i]]]]]] 
    [piperi\\{Modern Greek},name=MG]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: the result of the compilation]